# Async/await execution order

Tags: vb.net

**This is the program output:**

```
Program Begin
1 - Starting
2 - Task started
A - Started something
Program End
B - Completed something
3 - Task completed with result: 123
```

**Question:** As far i understand when it comes to *await* process is going back to main context so in this case to *Main* and then go back to *await* when it's finished so "A - Started something" should be after "Program End". Why this one line was shown? From my understanding when it comes to *away* it should immediatly go back to main context.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Program Begin");
            DoAsAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Program End");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async void DoAsAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Starting");
            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(DoSomethingThatTakesTime);
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Task started");
            var result = await t;
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Task completed with result: " + result);
        }

        static int DoSomethingThatTakesTime()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A - Started something");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("B - Completed something");
            return 123;
        }
```

Comment: This is why you should never use `async void`.

Comment: That's just coincidence that the other thread ran that then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far i understand when it comes to await process is going back to main context so in this case to Main and then go back to await when it's finished so "A - Started something" should be after "Program End".

That *is* what that thread is doing; the main thread is returning to the `Main` method.

However, `StartNew` will (in this case) execute its work on a thread pool thread, which runs independently from the main thread. So, you might see "A - Started something" before or after "Program End".

Comment: i thought task is not thread itself but could work on main thread asynchronously

Comment: @JimmyJimm: Yes, but by using `StartNew`, you're explicitly saying "run this task on a thread pool thread, not the UI thread".

Comment: so what you saying is when i type Task.Factory.StartNew - this means run on thread pool and when i would choose Task.Run?

Comment: @JimmyJimm: To be clear, you *should* use `Task.Run` to run code on a thread pool thread. Do not use `StartNew` at all - it's a low-level API that is very difficult to use correctly.

Comment: I decided to not use StartNew anymore but just Task.Run so i convert to it all i got with StartNew. But Task.Run is just shortcut for StartNew(with specific parameters..) so is it not the same?

Comment: @JimmyJimm: Yes, but **only** if you *also* provide the specific parameters (and call `Unwrap` if necessary). More info [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: ill stay with Task.Run :) and away/async approach

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to await, first the task get triggered, here it is "DoSomethingThatTakesTime". And then goes back to calling method to perform the next task/execution (here in your case it is Main()).

This will be much meaning full if you have another await in the main.

look into below example. very well explained.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674892.aspx

You may see a different result, if you call thread sleep before first print statement.

Comment: exactly so still don't get it...  task get triggered but should not go inside at this moment. Should go inside after "Program End"

Comment: That's not mandatory. Both are two different execution paths once "DoSomethingThatTakesTime" is triggered (two tasks running in parallel).

Comment: I would say main thread and task which works on that thread in behind.. When code reaches await it's calling back immediatly to the main context and then goes back again to await method therefore i do not understand both sequences.

Comment: "it is not goes back again". based on print statement you may feel like it goes back again. one execution comes back to main method and prints statements in main. The other execution goes to "DoSomethingThatTakesTime" prints statements there. Both are isolated

Comment: so i lost understanding of away keyword - i thought when it reaches it calls back to main context immediatly (not going to the DoSomethingThatTakesTime) at this point but after went back from Main. If not then why it's not continue executing away method but executing one statment of that method and goes back.

Comment: it is not going back. your second execution thread is sleeping.... in the mean time the first execution in main printed "Program End".

Comment: so it looks like it just goes to awa's method and executing it - when it comes to Thread.Sleep(1000) (long time operation) at this moment it goes to Main then Program End is printed and then goes back to away. So means it can jump even couple times between away method and Main?

Comment: At that point after reaching await, it starts/triggers new task (let us say T2) and goes back to Main( let us say TM). Now T2 and TM executes parallel. As you have "await" key word there, the next statements after "await" will be executed only after "T2" is complete

Comment: so at my example it could be lottery either Program End or A - Started something will be first one of them right?

Comment: Exactly..yes. it is.

Comment: Thats the reason I said in my answer to start another task in main, for better understanding.

Comment: ok thx, One more question: i heard diffrent opinions about Tasks - some people says that it no creating thread other people says they do and other sometimes yes sometime no, what true behind?

Comment: and output text i wrote is not static as two statments can be either first or second.

Comment: Yes. Both are true statements. Task look into thread pool and runs on available thread on thread pool. May be if thread pool is no reserve, then may create a new thread.